# Reducing modulo powers of a prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If p is an odd prime and a is coprime to p, how would one go about reducing $a^{p^{k-1}}\mod p^k$? Using Euler's formula we can get a value for $a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}\mod p^k$ but I can't really see how this is all that helpful...

For example how would you reduce $3^{625}\mod 5^5$?

Answer (score 1):

Euler's theorem is not really useful in this case because $p^{k-1}\leq \varphi(p^k)$ as your question pointed, because we are dealing with an element of a group so the proprieties of this element depends in his order and not much of the order of the group. Notice that calculating a power $\mod p^k$ is not really difficult in term of computation even for big numbers. for example the order $x$ of an element can be found  in $1+4\sqrt{x}+log(x)$ operations.

Your question can be solved by computing :$3 \mod 5^5$ , $3^5 \mod 5^5$ ,$(3^5)^5 \mod 5^5$ $ \cdots \cdots$ by computing each time the $5$th power of the result.

Mathematically speaking, the order of an element is very hard to find (there is no useful expression which gives the order of an arbitrary element $a$) . If we return to your question finding $a^{p^{k-1}}\mod p^k$ can be done using the following important result:

> **Theorem** (Lifting The Exponent Lemma):
>
> Given an positive integer $p$ (not necessarily a prime),If there exist two integers $n\leq m$ such that $a^{p^{m-n}}\equiv 1 \mod p^m $
> then for all $k\geq m$ we have $a^{p^{k-n}}\equiv 1 \mod p^k $

*Proof* : (by induction on $k$)

- **Basis step** : $k=m$ the result is true according to the hypothesis.
- **Induction step** : suppose that $ a^{p^{k-n}}\equiv 1 \mod p^k $ or in other words, there exist an integer $q$ such that $a^{p^{k-n}}=1+qp^k$ hence:
  $$a^{p^{k+1-n}}=(a^{p^{k-n}})^p=(1+qp^k)^p=1+p.qp^k+\sum_{i=2}^p \binom{p}{i}(qp^k)^i$$
  one can notice that $p^{k+1}|p.qp^k$ and $p^{k+1}|(qp^k)^i$ for every $i\geq 2$, thus $a^{p^{k+1-n}}\equiv 1\mod p^{k+1}$ which terminates the induction.

This theorem could not apply to you example because the order of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z_{5^5}}$ is $4.5^4$, but it works in other examples : we know that $5^{2^1}\equiv 1 \mod 2^3$ so for every $n\geq 3$  we have :
$$5^{2^{n-2}}\equiv 1 \mod 2^n $$

Comment: The result is sometimes called [Lifting The Exponent (LTE)](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h401494). I don't recall seeing any proofs on MSE. It would be nice if someone added one so that we do not need to link to offsite sources (such links often become stale).

Comment: Ok, let's do it!