# How do I prove this statement about $n^\text{th}$-power residues?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots, hensels-lemma

I am studying *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen, and the authors leave the proof of the following proposition (4.2.2) as "an exercise" ...

> Suppose that $a$ is odd, $e \geq 3$, and consider the congruence $$x^n \equiv a \pmod{2^e}$$
> Show that
>
> - If $n$ is odd, a solution for $x$ in the above congruence always exists and is unique.
> - If $n$ is even, a solution exists if and only if $a \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $$a^{2^{e-2}/d} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^e}$$ where $d= \gcd\left(n,2^{e-2}\right)$.

I figured I would try the $e=3$ case first. We are working with $$x^n \equiv a \pmod{8}$$

If $a$ is odd, then $a$ must be $1$, $3$, $5$, or $7$ modulo $8$. Further, if $n$ is odd, then the solution $x$ is simply equal to $a$, since (as we can easily check) any odd number raised to any odd power is equal to itself, modulo $8$ - every odd number is a square root of $1$. As for the other values of $e$ in the $n$ odd case, I think it should be possible to use Hensel's lemma in some way.

I have no idea how to start the $n$ even case. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: $a$ must be odd @gammatester

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Suppose $n$ is even and write $d=\gcd(n,2^{e-2})$, assume that there exists a solution to the equation:
   $$x^n\equiv a\mod 2^e $$
   because $a$ is odd then $x$ is odd and we have $a=1 \mod 4$ because $x^n\equiv (x^{\frac{n}{2}})^2\equiv 1\mod 4$, and we have also:
   $$x^{2}\equiv 1 \mod 8 $$
   using [Lifting The Exponent Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178325/reducing-modulo-powers-of-a-prime/1178423#1178423) we obtain:
   $$ x^{2^{e-2}}\equiv 1 \mod 2^e$$ 
   and this implies $a^{\frac{2^{e-2}}{d}}\equiv 1\mod 2^e$
2. Can you do the second implication?

Comment: In fact one does not need the full power of LTE here. A lower bound (with a much simpler proof) on the number of factors $2$ suffices to conclude $x^{2^{e-2}}\equiv1\pmod8$: if $a\equiv b\pmod{p^n}$, then $a^{p^k}\equiv b^{p^k}\pmod{p^{n+k}}$ for all $k$.

Comment: I think that this implication you mentioned in the comment is called itself a variation of LTE

Comment: Ah never mind. I thought you were using [a stronger form of LTE](http://www.academia.edu/4034266) which gives a precise value of the largest prime power dividing a thing. Apparently you're not; I hadn't visited the link yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The theorem in the book also goes on to state that for even $n$, if there is one solution, there are exactly $2d$ solutions, but I am struggling to show this as I can only prove the existence of $d$ solutions.  How would I go about this?